# How to whitelist types for serialization with CORDA

Tags: java, date, serialization, corda

I want to be able to pass `java.util.Date` to a [CORDA](https://www.corda.net/) API endpoint in a model

**The Model**

```
public final class Message{
    public Date birthday;

    public Message(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    private Message() {
        // This is only here so the serializer can spin up a new instance.
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }
}
```

**The API**

```
@Path("foo")
public final class FooApi {
    @PUT
    @Path("bar")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response putBar(Message m) {
        // Some logic here
        return Response.ok("Successful").build();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I submit a `Date`, I get this:

> Classjava.util.Dateisnotannotatedoronthewhitelist,
>   socannotbeusedinserializationSerializationtrace:
>   closeDate(com.template.messages.Message)

How do I whitelist `Date` for serialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Corda 1 onwards, you need to create a class that implements the `SerializationWhitelist` interface. Which is defined as:

```
interface SerializationWhitelist {
    val whitelist: List<Class<*>>
}
```

An example implementation might be:

```
class Plugin : SerializationWhitelist {
    override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> get() = listOf(
        TransactionBuilder::class.java
    )
}
```

In `META-INF.services` you then need a file called `net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist` in which you put the fully qualified class name of the class that implements `SerializationWhitelist`.

Cheers

Comment: Roger, would you mind adding a Corda V1 answer too, please?